# Error message without loading using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to create error message like this

> SPACE Not Allowed Please Try Again

If input is space in `firstname` and do I need to repeat the ajax for the lastname? It is not conflict while using another action `update.php` in form html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showError(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtError").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtError").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","resident/residenterrormessage.php?g="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="update.php" meth="POST">
  <div id="txtError">Error Message</div>
    <input  onchange="showError(this.value)"  title="First Name" name="firstname" type="text">
    <input title="Last Name" name="lastname" type="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  <input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my residenterrormessage.php in folder resident

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
  <?php

$firstname = str_replace(" ", "", $_GET["g"]);

if(empty($firstname) ){

     echo '<h1>"SPACE Not Allowed Please Try Again"</h1>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you are appending an whole page inside the div. So i did some editing in your code. You might wanna try to edit your residenterrormessage.php to this

```
  <?php

if(empty(str_replace(" ","",$_GET["q"]))){
 echo '<h1>SPACE Not Allowed Please Try Again</h1>';
}
else
{
echo "a";
}
?>
```